# Anaconda says unable to create process on windows10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I have installed Anaconda3 on my Windows 10 machine. Installation complete all fine. Then i added the in %PATH%. But when I am trying to launch anaconda prompt it says that

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\anjaneya\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\anjaneya\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py ..checkenv "cmd.exe" "C:\Users\anjaneya\Anaconda3"'
```

Not sure what is wrong. Please help.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem as you. After some groping, I solved it.
You can try the following method:

Open cmd in this directory

> C:\Users\anjaneya\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\anjaneya\Anaconda3\Scripts

then input：

```
>conda list
```

Then I found out that my program is working properly.

I hope I can help you