# Anaconda is unable to create process on Windows10

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, windows-10

When I am trying to launch Anaconda prompt it says that

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py shell.cmd.exe activate activate C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013469/anaconda-says-unable-to-create-process-on-windows10) I tried to run `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts` but I got 
`'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: related? https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the following command in your terminal to activate the conda environment:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate
```

You need to replace YOUR_USERNAME with your own username. If you have installed conda at some custom-specified location, only then you need to replace the initial part of the command (C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Anaconda3\Scripts) with the path of actual conda installation.

After activating, conda commands would work in the terminal.

Comment: D:\temp\anaconda\pkgs\conda-4.10.1-py38haa95532_1\Scripts>activate
failed to create process.

D:\temp\anaconda\pkgs\conda-4.10.1-py38haa95532_1\Scripts>activate.bat
failed to create process.

no luck

Comment: This script is missing in my installation. Is this a newer version? Is there a different procedure in an older version?

Answer (score 3):

Start by uninstalling Anaconda from the `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\anaconda3` directory then restart your Pc. Now download and install the latest Anaconda distribution only this time when the installer pops up, make sure to select install for all users as shown below:

[image]

This should resolve the error without any hitches.

Also note that using `JUST ME` may not work after you've installed Anaconda since your user name may have a whitespace, i.e `C://USERS//USER NAME` therefore the shell command that activates conda fails due to the subprocess being unable to reach the breakpoint `C://USERS//USER"+" NAME//conda//jupyter.exe`